# Google Sheets button that toggles a row of checkboxes on/off

Tags: javascript, button, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm very, very new to JavaScript and Google Sheets. I'm trying to learn it, but it's very confusing.

I have a row of checkboxes in Sheet1, cells E4 to L4.
Below them, I have a button.

What I want to happen is, when you click the button:

- If ANY of the checkboxes in cells E4 to L4 are UNCHECKED, then set them ALL to be CHECKED.
- IF, however, ALL the checkboxes in E4 to L4 are already CHECKED, then set them ALL to be UNCHECKED.

This is what I have so far:

```
function ToggleALLBoxes() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 var range = sheet.getRange('E4:L4');
 var value = range.getValue();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a way to do what I needed using two buttons instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using one button, by applying a toggle in the script like so:

```js
function ToggleALLBoxes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  var range = sheet.getRange('E4:L4');
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  if(values.indexOf(false) < 0){
    Logger.log("All checked")
    // Set them to unchecked
    range.setValue("FALSE");   
  }else {
    Logger.log("Not all checked")
    // Set all to checked
    range.setValue("TRUE");    
  }
}
```

And assigning the function to the image of the button like:

[image]